# A more efficient options object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I currently create an object on page load with all possible key/value pairs and use true or false to determine their state. It would be more efficient if only items that were true were present though.

Sample data:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": {
                2: false,
                3: true,
                4: false,
                5: false,
                6: false,
                7: false
            },
            "Gender": {
                1: false,
                2: false
            },
            "NEWSEC": {
                1: false,
                2: true,
                3: false,
                4: false,
                5: false
            },
            "Telco_Segment": {
                1: true,
                2: true,
                3: true,
                4: false,
                5: false,
                6: false
            }
    };
```

function:

```
function facetBuilder(key, val)
{
    if(key == 'country')
    {   
        filter.country = val;
    }
    else
    {
        if( filter[key][val] == true )
        {
            filter[key][val] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            filter[key][val] = true;
        }
    }
    console.log(filter);
}
```

Problem:

The function I use to apply these filters loops through them, so it would be more beneficial if I only had the objects such as "Age Group" present if it contained any values. In fact, it would be nice to have something like the following:

```
    filter =  {
            "country": 1,
            "Age Group": [3],
            "NEWSEC": [2],
            "Telco_Segment": [1,2,3]
    };
```

calling facetBuilder would essentially add/remove an object based on the presence of value(s) for that object.

I'm drawing a blank on how to approach this one.

Comment: Well, if I'm not missing anything here, just don't set the false values - they'll be undefined, which evaluates to false if you ever need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly check for `true`. You can check for the existence for an entry by doing something like this:

```
if(map[key]) {
  ...
  ...
}
```

However if the value associated with that key is `0`, then this is a problem, so it's better to do:

```
if(typeof map[key] !== "undefined") {
   ...
   ...
}
```

The reason you want to use `typeof` in this case is that a direct comparison against `undefined` can be problematic due to the possibility of `undefined` being overwritten by other code:

```
window.undefined = "not undefined";
"not undefined" == "undefined" //returns a true value
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
if(typeof filter[key][val] !== "undefined" )
{
    delete filter[key][val]; //I'm assuming you want to remove it
}
else
{
    filter[key][val] = true;
}
```

Another thing, when checking for a true value, it's enough to say

```
if([expression that evaluates to a boolean value]) {
    ...
}
```

You don't have to do:

```
if([expression that evaluates to a boolean value] == true) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if([expression that evaluates to a boolean value] == false) {
    ...
}
```

Another way to check for the existence of a property is to use the `in` operator:

```
var stuff = {
   a: 10,
   c: 20,
   d: 30
};

var ay = "a"
console.log(ay in blab, "b" in blab, "c" in blab, "d" in blab);
>>true false true true
```

I'm assuming this is what you want to do. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I never get why `typeof x !== "undefined"` is used instead of `x !=== undefined` *in the general case of comparing for the undefined value*. The *only* time I use `typeof x` is when the *reference denoted by `x`* might not be in scope. E.g. `if (r !=== undefined) { ... }` would be a TypeError if `r` is not a local variable and there is no `window.r` property. (Also, if someone redefines `undefined` then the code is already broken; this is a case I *do not* consider valid for arguments sake.)

Comment: @pst A direct comparison against `undefined` can be problematic because `undefined` can be overwritten. For exmaple: `window.undefined = "not undefined";`. Then, `"not undefined" == undefined;` evaluates to `true`. This used to be a problem; not so sure if it is now. I generally now do it because of force of habit and a bit of paranoia.

Comment: ...which is a argument because `True` and `False` can be overwritten in Python 2.6 and before yet people never throughout the logicals assumptions of the values they evaluated to. If `undefined` is redefined then *the code is already broken*. (And yes, while the argument is pedantically correct, programming is all about operating under an established set of assumptions and waving hands about wildly if they are violated.)

Comment: @pst I completely agree. But in Javascript you often have third-party code which can be broken and which can do weird things. So I prefer to err on the side of caution (or paranoia) :).

Comment: In any case, thanks for explaining the choice of `typeof x` (+1). A little note in the post might be useful to others ;) Also, what about the use of `in` here for pros/cons for key existence checks?

Comment: @pst oops totally forgot about `in`. Will add that!